# JQuery Theme Not Working in Server

Tags: jquery, css, zend-framework

I'm using JQuery's DatePicker with the "Start" theme. It displays correctly using that theme on my local machine. But when I uploaded it to our server it doesn't display like it did locally. The calendar shows but the look is wrong.

The only difference I can observer is: In my local machine I use "http://". When I view it on our server I use "https://".

Here's a snippet of my Zend Framework code (Layout).

```
$this->headLink()
                ->appendStylesheet('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css');

$this->headScript()
                ->prependFile('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js')
                ->prependFile('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js');
```

Then in my Index Controller:

```
$this->headScript()
->setScript('$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
    });')

<div class="left">Date: <input type="text" size="7" id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried to put https:// on this code which is for css in above mention in your question :  $this->headLink()
                ->appendStylesheet('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css');

Comment: now i have faced the same issue. thanks for posting query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly the stylesheet is being blocked if the site is running in https, in this case some browsers wont load unsecure content, only the secure content gets loaded.

ie 
->appendStylesheet('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css');

if you have any developers tools installed on your web browser, you may want to check to see if the stylesheet loads or not. Chrome has a network console that shows whether individual files loaded successfully or not.

If this is the case you could try changing 
->appendStylesheet('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css');

to 
->appendStylesheet('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css');

or
->appendStylesheet('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css');